# Merging values from two fields into third field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, editing, features

I have two fields which I want to merge into a single field, thereby should one of the two to-be-merged fields be prioritized, meaning, if a value of one field is available take it instead of the other field.

I would like to have it like this:

```
field1 | field2 | resultField
-----------------------------
13     | NULL   | 13
28     | 56     | 56
44     | NULL   | 44
11     | 17     | 17
```

So the `"field2"` should be prioritized in the resulting field.

I know, that I will need to create a new field, with the name relevant field name, so

```py
vectorLyr =  QgsVectorLayer('path_to_filed', 'layername', "ogr")
vectorLyr.isValid()

vpr = vectorLyr.dataProvider()

fieldnames = [resultField]

for name in fieldnames:
    vpr.addAttributes([QgsField(name, QVariant.Double)])
    vectorLyr.updateFields()
```

However, how can I now update the `"resultfield"` with the values from the two fields?

Comment: I'm confused: Why was my code 'edited' without being changed in any way?

Comment: Editing is a normal part of these sites.  In the above case, the tag `pyqgis` was added to the backticks to tell it how to colourize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `or` like this, i think it is called [Ternary operators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
p = layer.dataProvider()
field_to_update = "field3"
fieldindex = layer.fields().indexOf(field_to_update)

attributemap = {} #A dictionary to store {feature id: {index of field to update : new value}}
for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature
    f1, f2 = f["field1"], f["field2"] #Extract the values in field1 and field2
    attributemap[f.id()] = {fieldindex: f2 or f1 or -999} #Take the first not null value, or if there is none, use -999

#attributemap[1]
#{4: 83} Feature 1 should in field 4 get the value 83

p.changeAttributeValues(attributemap)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, this looks very nice, kind of elegant! Thank you very much, I will try it!

Comment: I adjusted my code accordingly and ran into a little problem: Python interpretes the value 0 as NULL, so that all values which are 0 or NULL become -999. However, 0 is 0 and not 'None'. Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Oh. Try replacing `f2 or f1 or -999` with `next(item for item in [f2, f1, -999] if item is not None)`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be not as Pythonic as was suggested by @BERA, however, it is still applicable in terms of PyQGIS.

It utilizes the [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#coalesce) function inside the [`QgsExpression()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsExpression.html) class.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils

# refer to a layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("lines")[0]

# set up an expression including two desired fields
expression = QgsExpression('coalesce("field1", "field2")')

# define the expression context to encapsulate parameters for evaluation
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

# start layer editing
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(feat)
        feat["result"] = expression.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like:

[image: result]

P.S. To achieve -999 where `"field1"` and `"field2"` are both `NULL`s, please modify the expression accordingly:

```py
expression = QgsExpression('coalesce("field1", "field2", -999)')
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 11. Expressions, Filtering and Calculating Values](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html)