# Using raster_value(layer,band,point) function in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, expression

I have successfully used the raster_value(layer,band,point) function as an expression in the field calculator GUI of QGIS. However, I am struggling to use the expression in PyQGIS. So far, my code looks as follows:

```
input_layer=r'test.gpkg|layername=test_points'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(input_layer, "layer", "ogr")
if vlayer.isValid():
    print("This is a valid vector layer!")
else:
    print("This vector layer is invalid!")
# Ad raster layer
uri = r"raster.tif"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "dtm", "gdal")

if rlayer.isValid():
    print("This is a valid raster layer!")
else:
    print("This raster layer is invalid!")
## Add field
pr = vlayer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("Raster_value", QVariant.Double)])
vlayer.updateFields()
##
expression = QgsExpression('raster_value(rlayer,1,$geometry)')

# Set QgsExpressionContext 
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(vlayer))
# Update fields
vlayer.startEditing()
for f in vlayer.getFeatures():
    context.setFeature(f)
    context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(rlayer))
    f['Raster_value'] = expression.evaluate(context)
    vlayer.updateFeature(f)
vlayer.commitChanges()
##
```

However, this seems not to work, the field is just updated with "None". I guess I did not correctly set up the expression context only referring to the vector layer.

How do I add the raster to the expression context, so the raster_value expression works properly?

Comment: The field is just updated with "None"

Answer (score 1):

See: [PyQGIS Calculate Geometry and Field Values with the QGIS Python API](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-calculate-geometry-and-field-values-with-the-qgis-python-api/)

Try this:

```
pointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Random points")[0]

#Add the field rastervalue
pointlayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("rastervalue", QVariant.Double)])
pointlayer.updateFields()

#Create the expression
exp = QgsExpression("raster_value( 'nh_66_5', 1, $geometry)") #My raster layer is named nh_66_5
print(exp.isValid())
#True

#Set the context
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(pointlayer))

#Calculate
with edit(pointlayer):
    for f in pointlayer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['rastervalue'] = exp.evaluate(context)
        pointlayer.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! How did you find out your raster layers name is 'nh_66_5' and can you do that in code? My tries all got stuck at that point.

Comment: It's the name of the layer in the layers panel to the left in my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it as an expression? I have not been able to get the raster_value expression to run, either - but I have a workaround for this specific case.

Use `rlayer.dataProvider().sample(...)` to get a raster band value for a coordinate.

The code that works for me is

```
input_layer=r'test.gpkg|layername=test_points'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(input_layer, "layer", "ogr")
if vlayer.isValid():
    print("This is a valid vector layer!")
else:
    print("This vector layer is invalid!")
# Add raster layer
uri = r"srtm_germany_dtm.tif"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "dtm", "gdal")

if rlayer.isValid():
    print("This is a valid raster layer!")
else:
    print("This raster layer is invalid!")

with edit(vlayer):
    for f in vlayer.getFeatures():
        # sample the raster layer, band 1, at the point location of f
        v = rlayer.dataProvider().sample(f.geometry().asPoint(),1)
        print(v)
        # sample() returns a tuple, first item is the raster value
        # second item is a boolean indicating if the raster contained the point
        if v[1] == True:
            f['Raster_value'] = v[0]
            vlayer.updateFeature(f)
```